# PDF version 1.5 and higher not able to view/download in browser

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I'm developing a vb.net web application. Recently I face a problem where the PDF file with version 1.5 and higher are not able to view/download through browser. When I click the link to view the PDF file, the browser will prompt a "File Download" message box, when I choose to open the PDF file, the adobe reader display this error "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired." Even if I choose "Save" to PC then open the PDF file, it still display the same error message.

The code I'm using for view attachment is as below:

`HTTPContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/PDF"
HTTPContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; Filename=XXX.pdf")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(System.IO.FileInfo(FILE_PATH).FullName)
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`

There is no issue when viewing the PDF version 1.4 and below.
Is there any issue with the code? Any solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for any file type:

```
Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM"
Dim Header As [String] = "Attachment; Filename=MyFile.PDF"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header)
Response.BinaryWrite(MyFile.pdf)
Response.[End]()
```

Adjust accordingly.

NOTE:  There are issues with Adobe Reader in protected mode which may be solved with a settings change.  Check this link:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2208915

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it still didn't work, and I manage to find out only some attachment have issues with viewing through web application. Seems like it is not related to the PDF version.

Comment: Huh ... I use this code to download any file, straight out of my database, never had an issue.  What version of Visual Studios (VS) are you using?  I assume you use VS.  Are you getting the same exact error message?

Comment: I added a link in my answer that may help.  Seems to me I remember having the same issue at one time with Adobe Reader.

Comment: At last, I try to re-scan the attachment and send to my mail as PDF file, then upload to the web application and it works fine. I can view the PDF file and download as well. I'm not sure why the first time scanning PDF file have problem. Looks like nothing wrong with the web application program.